# Why am I getting ECONNREFUSED connecting to localhost MySQL from docker node app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, docker

I have a locally running MySQL server.. it's NOT within a container. My app is going to be hitting RDS so no sense in going that route. My app was able to hit RDS no problem, as a test. But obviously I want to hit something local for local development.

From my terminal I can do `mysql --user=root --password=password mydb` successfully.

And as I'm not getting a timeout error, from my container I can `ping 127.0.0.1:3306` with no issue.

I also used console to see I am definitely passing the right info, after having updated the values from RDS to locally running MySQL.

Comment: Generally you don't use `ping` with a specific port as `ping` will use ICMP packets. Have you instead verified that the mysql server is listening on the intended address and port using something like `netstat -nlp`?

Comment: Alternatively if the mysql server is listening on a UNIX socket, you can connect to that instead from node as well using the `socketPath` connection config option with either the `mysql` or `mysql2` modules.

Comment: @mscdex In terms of netstat, is there a reason I would see 3306 pop up if my app isn't trying to keep an open connection? Certainly not listed there now and I don't think I'd expect it to be.

Comment: I wouldn't wanna use socketPath here since I didn't need to for the AWS connection, so I don't wanna use diff methods between local and not

Answer (score 4):

Docker container has its own network IPs, including its own `localhost`. So you basically need to be sure of two things:

1. That your host MySQL is listening in all of its interfaces (bind-addres = 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf). Check with `netstat -na|grep 3306`.
2. Figure out the host ip that your container **can** reach. So check the IP of the container: `docker inspect container-id`, find the IP, and replace the last part with `.1`, that should be the IP of your host in the containers own network. I.e. `172.17.0.1` (it can be considered as fixed IP, for dev environment it's ok)

So most likely that this is what you need: `172.17.0.1:3306`

Comment: Mine was 18, instead of 17, but no dice.

Comment: oh my goodness... I've spent hours on this (and was looking at one of your other posts on docker/mysql stuff) and changing 127.0.0.1:3306 to 172.17.0.1:3306 finally got it. Thank you so much!